# How to include regular expression on a file for 'tar' command option '-T'

Tags: bash, tar, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to archive my project directories and files using `-T, --files-from` option.

Here's a sample that similar to my project setup

```
testproj
|
|__testapp
|  |
|  |__src
|  |  |
|  |  |__test1.js
|  |  |__test2.js
|  |  |__test3.js
|  |  |
|  |__static
|  |  |
|  |  |__main.js
|  |  |
|  |__templates
|  |  |
|  |  |__main.html
|  |  |
|  |  test1.py
|  |  test2.py
|  |  test3.py
|  |  db1.db
|  |  db2.db
|  |  |
|  tarlists.txt
|  test.sh
```

'tarlists.txt' contains these lines:

```
testapp/static
testapp/templates
testapp/*.py
```

I think its obvious but still I want to state that I don't want to include 'testapp/src' and 'db' files

When I try to create tar.gz (I execute this at testproj directory):

```bash
$ tar czvf testproj.tar.gz -T tarlists.txt
testapp/static/
testapp/static/main.js
testapp/templates/
testapp/templates/main.html
tar: testapp/*.py: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

files with .py files aren't included

but if I try this

```bash
$ tar czvf testproj.tar.gz testapp/*.py
testapp/test1.py
testapp/test2.py
testapp/test3.py
```

It works.

Is my regular expression is wrong in 'tarlists.txt'? then how do I properly include a regular expression in the file?

Comment: Try adding the `--wildcards` option to `tar`. In your second example, the wildcard expansion is done by the shell.

Comment: @sj95126 I tried your suggestion by doing these `tar czvf testproj.tar.gz --wildcards -T tarlists.txt`, the results still the same, it won't add .py files which I wanted to. Please tell me if my command is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, apparently `--wildcards` doesn't work for creating tarfiles with `-T`. Some versions of the man page state this, mine did not. You may have to generate `tarlists.txt` with `find` or similar, so it has all filenames in it.

Comment: That's not a regular expression: it's a glob.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`, this should work unless your filenames or directory names contain some weird characters (e.g., newline character):

```
tar czvf testproj.tar.gz -T <(IFS=$'\n'; printf '%s\n' $(<tarlists.txt))
```

Note that there's no regular expression involved. Patterns like `testapp/*.py` that are subject to filename expansion are called `glob`s.